# Does repartition not shuffle data to all nodes?

Tags: apache-spark

Consider the following simple example, run the Spark Shell connected to a Cluster with 4 Executors:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 4).cache.setName("rdd")
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = rdd ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> rdd.count()
res0: Long = 6
```

[image: rdd]

```
scala> val singlePartition = rdd.repartition(1).cache.setName("singlePartition")
singlePartition: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = singlePartition MapPartitionsRDD[4] at repartition at <console>:29

scala> singlePartition.count()
res1: Long = 6
```

[image: singlePartition]

```
scala> val multiplePartitions = singlePartition.repartition(6).cache.setName("multiplePartitions")
multiplePartitions: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = multiplePartitions MapPartitionsRDD[8] at repartition at <console>:31

scala> multiplePartitions.count()
res2: Long = 6
```

[image]

The original `rdd` has 4 partitions which when I check in the UI are distributed across the 4 Executors.  The `singlePartition` RDD is obviously only contained on one Executor.  And when the `multiplePartitions` RDD is created by repartitioning the  `singlePartition` RDD and I would expect that to shuffle the data across the 4 Executors.  What I see is that there are 6 partitions for `multiplePartitions`, but they are all on one Executor, the same one where `singlePartition` has its partition.

Shouldn't the data be shuffled across the 4 Executors by the repartition?

Comment: Perhaps it is related to this issue? https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/8280